# Recording Flip flops in Foley

Tags: foley

How do you people record flip flop steps in foley? The usual technique for other kinds of shoes doesn't work, because of how the shoe interacts with the foot and the floor. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hi Charles, great question. I remember seeing a Soundworks video about 'the social network' and it included some talk on flip flops (mark zuckerberg used to run around on them. It was a vert specific flip flop and the director wanted that to be obvious to the viewer. I'll look for a link (kn mobiel now)

Comment: http://soundworkscollection.com/videos/socialnetworkpanel Somewhere in this video they talk about the flip flops, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I had to do flip flop footsteps once, and it was pretty difficult.
I had a square surface about 50cm x 50cm made of concrete to walk on (small surface).
the tricks I had udsed for footsteps foley didn´t work...
the only advice I can tell you is just put your headphones on, close your eyes and start walking (or what ever movement needed) looking for the sound you need.
I remember I had to do some pushing with my toes in order to have the "flip flop" sound" and my movements were everything except walking. LOL
I found that the flip flop works better if the size is bigger than your foot (just one size or so)

enjoy the foley!!